# PHP create API connecting 2 Applications on same server

Tags: php, mysql, api

Imagine 2 Applications running with different mysql-databases on the same server.
I need a way to exchange data between both applications. 
One Application has no permission to access the database of the other application.
The exchange is only backend related (automatic stuff), no user interaction needed.

What would be the best and safest way to do this using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use named pipes - they're well suited for interprocess communication.

http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/29/php-and-named-pipes

You can try it out in the interactive php:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:~ dearlbry$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > posix_mkfifo("test-pipe", 0644);
php > $pipe = fopen('test-pipe','r+');
php > print fgets($pipe);
```

Let that sit there waiting, then open another terminal:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:~ dearlbry$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $pipe = fopen('test-pipe','r+');
php > fwrite($pipe, "Hello World\n");
php > fclose($pipe);
```

Watch the "Hello World" show up in the first process. Make sure you put in the "\n", as pipes are buffered and the newline signals to flush it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API where by one application could POST and GET data to and from the other.

```
// From application2.com

$id = $curl->post('http://application1.com/users/save/', array(
    'name' => 'Matt',
    'bio' => 'I am a person.'
));

// $id is generated from a DB insert

$user = $curl->post('http://application1.com/users/bio/', array(
    'id' => $id
));

// $user contains an array or object of information about Matt
```

Comment: thanks first. I was wondering if there is a better way (not using apache) while both application are on the same server?

Comment: Give the databases permission to talk to each other?

Comment: i wouldnt ask this question if i could

Comment: both apps need to communicate with each other.
exchange information, but not much. at most 100 characters at once (short strings)
If there is no other way, im fine with it, so ill build a rest api. apparently there isnt, but i wasnt sure...